# Google Cloud Storage: Upload a lot of small files at once?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

is there any good strategy to upload 100s of thousands of files at once?
Uploading through fuse takes ages, naturally. Is there a way to upload a tar and unzip it on GCS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, that was easy:

`gsutil -m rsync -d -r uploads`

gsutil in general has a lot of options and is much faster than fuse.